# Why the origin of contentview doesn't coincide the origin of scrollview when application setup?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller

[The problem shows in the gif picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAhy6.gif) (The view in yellow is the contentview. The view in black is the scrollview.)

[The whole project code on Github.](https://github.com/UtopiaCHN/ProblemSolving.git)

Here is the code :

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake( 50, 100, 200, 200);
UIScrollView *scrollView= [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

frame= CGRectMake( 0, 0, 500, 500);
UIImageView *myImageView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[scrollView addSubview:myImageView];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(500,500);

scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
myImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0)
```

One more problem shows in the picture:
Why the horizontal scrollbar is not at bottom of scrollview?

When I added a view between the scrollview and self.view the problem disappeared.

The code that I added:

```
UIView *view = [UIView new];
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

I found that the problem happened when I used UITabBarController.

Comment: your code works fine

Comment: I created a new project with the code above-mentioned. Then everything works fine. Maybe something wrong in other code.

Comment: When I added a view between the scrollview and self.view the problem disappeared.

Comment: make an answer of this..so others can benefit from it

Comment: I found that the problem happened when I used UITabBarController. I upload the code to github. You can get the url in question description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the UIScrollView a global variable. Make the contentInset of the UIScrollView and UIScrollView's indicators UIEdgeInsetsZero when the views are loaded like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    _scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    _scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. And I want to know what cause the problem.

Comment: Maybe it is a default issue when the UIScrollView is the top most view in the UIViewController after the main view. Because the edges were the same as UINavigationBar height and UITabBar height.

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough reputation to do that.

Comment: I have another problem that I'm  really frustrated with. Can you help me?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33605379/when-two-labels-show-side-by-side-with-using-the-masonry-how-to-make-the-width

Comment: Sorry. I don't have experience with Masonry.