# When two labels show side by side with using the Masonry, how to make the width of each label show depending on its content?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel, masonry, ios-autolayout

I want to use the Masonry to show two labels (UILabel) in the a line (view). But the left label is much wider than the right one. [They shows like that in this picture.(The green label and yellow label.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8K4u.png)

The content compression of them are UILayoutPriorityRequired, I want the left side of the left label is equal to its superview and the right side of the right label is equal to its superview. Then how to make the width of each label show depending on its content with even more labels in a view?

Here is my code:

```
_label1 = [UILabel new];
_label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
_label1.text = @"label,";

_label2 = [UILabel new];
_label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
_label2.text = @"label,";

[_contentView1 addSubview:_label1];
[_contentView1 addSubview:_label2];

[_label1 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.equalTo(_contentView1.mas_top).with.offset(5);
    make.left.equalTo(_contentView1.mas_left).with.offset(2);
    make.height.equalTo(@40);
}];

[_label2 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

    make.left.equalTo(_label1.mas_right).with.offset(2);
    make.top.equalTo(_contentView1.mas_top).with.offset(5);
    make.right.equalTo(_contentView1.mas_right).with.offset(-2);
    make.height.equalTo(@40);
}];

[_label1 setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired
                           forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];

[_label1 setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired
                                         forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];

[_label2 setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired
                           forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];

[_label2 setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired
                                         forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
```

Answer (score -1):

`http://swiftcn.io/topics/32`
Set content hugging and content compression.
(中国人吧？)

Comment: 我设置了，我把相关的代码贴上去了，怎么没效果啊，感觉是ContentHugging没效果。

Comment: ...你设置label1.width 和 label2.width一样啊

Comment: 但是 label1 和 label2 的内容长度不一样，所以不能设置一样。。

Comment: 你要什么效果啊？“ Then how to make the width of each label show depending on its content with even more labels in a view?” 看不懂你在说什么

Comment: 额，就是label的宽度由内容多少决定，同时最左边和最右边的label分别紧靠父视图的左边和右边。

Comment: 删了 make.left.equalTo(_label1.mas_right).with.offset(2);